# What does it mean to have arup payos?

Tags: halacha, minhag, payot-sideburns

What does it mean to have arup payos? 
What specific style or length is this?
Who would have the minhag to keep their payos in such a fashion that is called "arup"?

Comment: Also what does it mean to have "arouf payos"? website won't let me ask as a seperate question so adding it on to this one...

Comment: Where have you heard the term?

Comment: shidduch website. one of the questions was what style payos do you have and there was a drop down menu for options

Comment: @Yishai It does NOT imply not trimming, only letting them hang down in front of the ears. E.g. In Satmar, prevailing custom is trimming (or burning) the payos to chin-length as they hang naturally, whether curly or straight.

Comment: @Yishai Actually "arup" (אַראָפּ) means *down* in Yiddish

Comment: @SAH, yes, for some reason the transliteration reversed things in my mind.

Comment: I wonder if arup payes means payes that aren't curled or groomed at all, but just hang there...

Comment: @dude Which shidduch website is that? it sounds pretty awesome:)

Comment: @Adám People burn off the ends of their payos? Who? Why?

Comment: @SAH Personally, I know e.g. the family of the Shotzer Rebbe in Montreal. Why? To keep them no longer than until the chin, in the belief that anything beyond that is considered normal hair.

Comment: @Adám So if it's normal hair then why couldn't they cut them

Comment: @SAH Maybe because it borders on payos. I can ask.

Comment: @Adám You don't have to! Only if you're interested too. It would be nice to find out. Wow, machmirus truly knows no "ends"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an interesting [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payot) describing different payot styles.

"As Yishai mentioned, above, "aruf" means "up" so this refers to payot that are behind the ear vs. hanging down. It could be either tied up and put under the kippah or curled around the ear. According to the wiki article this is considered the common "Litvish" / yeshivish style. That may explain why you have seen this on the shidduch web site.

Comment: "Arup" (אַראָפּ) actually means /down/ in Yiddish. No idea what the implications are for peyos...

Comment: @sah Arop means down,but Arof or Aruf means up